# Forms in Java web application?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, jsp-tags

What is the best practice to create form validation and submission on JSP page? Is there any controls or JavaBeans or API or Interface available which are similar to controls in ASP.NET?

Comment: Use javascript for form validation on client side. I am also looking like you problems if there is any updates then let me know.

Answer (score 2):

you provide both client side validation as well as server side validation.
for client side validation you can use any Java script based frameworks(JQuery or prototype).
for server side validation you use framework provided API(Struts,Spring or JSF) if u use any.

Comment: I am not using simple JSP pages for my application. This is application is used for the staff only and maximum no of logedin at once will not be more then 5.

Comment: if it is very small application i mean functionality wise then u better write ur own validation for both client side and server side.because for small functionality I do not recommend using a framework like struts and spring.as a best practise u write both client side and server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Your MVC framework (like Struts or Spring MVC) can provide the kind of form validation and submission you're looking for. Depends on which framework you're using.